# How to export the kendo grid with two decimal places (with culture)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I have a grid and my data contains 3 decimal places for the numeric property value. I want to export the grid and still have the decimal format to 2 places. But it's not happening. It displays 2 decimal places in the grid but when I click export, it becomes 3 decimal places in the excel file. The reason I use "{0:N2}") so that when I use other culture, it will display accordingly.
What is the best way to do it?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Box>()
        .Name("gridKendo")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(l => l.Name).Locked(true);
            columns.Bound(l => l.Length).Format("{0:N2}");
            columns.Bound(l => l.Length2).Format("{0:N2}");
            columns.Bound(l => l.Length3).Format("{0:N2}");
        })
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Create().Text("Add Book");
            toolBar.Excel();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .Sortable(sortable => sortable
            .AllowUnsort(true)
            .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Excel(excel => excel
            .FileName("Excel.xlsx")
            .Filterable(true)
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Grid")) 
        )
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .WebApi()
            .PageSize(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Kendo UI's [Excel Export & Column Formats](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/excel-export#column-format) documentation:

> Kendo UI Grid doesn't use column formats during Excel export because
>   some Kendo UI formats are incompatible with Excel.
>
> To format the cell values set the [format](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook.html#configuration-sheets.rows.cells.format) option of the cells.
>
> The [Create a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) page describes the formats that
>   Excel supports.
>
> The [Cell Format](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/excel/cell-format) tutorial shows how to format the cell values.